# long click triggers click, long click doesn't get registered

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview in a `constraintlayout`.
when I try to do a long click on one of the elements of the list, to inflate the context menu, there are 2 problems:

1: It triggers the long click only sometimes, really random

2: After the long click was triggered the "normal" click is also triggered even though the onContextItemSelected returns true (to indicate the event was handled)

for some list elements, I want to have both the `onClickListener` and the long click for the contextmenu, on others only the contextmenu. (the listview is registered for contextmenu).
Heres the XML of the MainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="it.netknights.piauthenticator.MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/PIBLUE"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/countdownfield"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/PIBLUE"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/PIBLUE"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:popupTheme="@color/PIBLUE"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-57dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/countdownfield"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the XML of the **listentry**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:longClickable="true"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewToken"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="124891"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

<!--    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"-->



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewLabel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="privacyidea something"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewToken"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewLabel"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.517"
    />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

the part of the MainActivity.java

```
final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "SHORT itemclick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
registerForContextMenu(listview);
```

and the `getview` method from my custom adapter:

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (v == null) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tokenentry, parent, false);
    }
    v.setLongClickable(true);
    v.setTag(position);

    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    final Token token = getItem(position);
    final TextView tmp2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewToken);
    final TextView tmp1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewLabel);


    if (token.getType().equals(HOTP)) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
    } else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        //v.setClickable(false);
    }

    progressBar.setTag(position);
    progressBar.setMax(token.getPeriod());
    progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
            Color.rgb(0x83, 0xc9, 0x27), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    token.setPb(progressBar);

    tmp1.setText(token.getLabel());
    tmp2.setText(token.getCurrentOTP());
```

**EDIT:** thank you for taking your time to post answers.
Ive solved the/my problem: the rootelement of the listentries was a contraintlayout and that doesn't seem to work properly with the scenarios i want, so i changed it so a relativelayout and it now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

hi Cxc the problem might be due to listView registered for both onClick and onLongClick . So instead of setting the onClickListener for the entire list view try setting the onClick listener to only the item view for which you need both onClickListener and long click.
You can set onClickListener to particular views inside getView() method based on their position or view type.
for example,

```
      @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (v == null) {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tokenentry, parent, false);
        }
        v.setLongClickable(true);
        v.setTag(position);
       if(position % 2 == 0)
       {
            v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "SHORT itemclick", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }

        });
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use both onClick and onLongClick and override the onLongClick method making it returns true to avoid conflict of triggering onClick event

ex:

```
GridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                <do somthing here>

        }
    });

    GridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, final int i, long l) {

            <do something here>
return true;
        }
    });
```